# Sonata Type Collection (Symfony3), añadir y editar formulario en una nueva ventana (popup)

Tags: php, formularios, symfony3, doctrine, popup

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con sonata admin y tengo dos entidades, con una relación OneToMany y un `ArrayCollection` para manejarlo.

En la clase Admin de esta entidad, tengo un `Sonata Type Collection` en el form mapper que me enseña el formulario de la otra entidad (puedo añadir, editar y borrar), pero necesito tener una lista con identificadores y cuando se da clic a una, abrir una ventana (como un overlay y popup) y allí tener la vista del formulario.

Pongo imagenes para aclarlo un poco mejor:

Ahora tengo esto:
  [Imagen de como esta ahora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PGIb.png)

Y quiero tener una lista, y cuando quiera añadir una nueva noticia, o editar alguna o dar clic y tener algo así:
[Imagen de objetivo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbEXO.png)

Esta es mi entidad `News`:

```
<?php
  namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Customer;

/**
 * NewsCustomer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_customer")
 * 
 */
class NewsCustomer
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="headline", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $headline;

    /**
     * @var Customer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="newsCustomer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customer;


    /**
     * To String
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->getHeadline());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set headline
     *
     * @param string $headline
     *
     * @return NewsCustomer
     */
    public function setHeadline($headline)
    {
        $this->headline = $headline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get headline
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeadline()
    {
        return $this->headline;
    }

    /**
     * Set customer
     *
     * @param Customer $customer
     *
     * @return NewsCustomer
     */
    public function setCustomer(Customer $customer = null)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer
     *
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }
}
```

Entitad `Customers` (oneToMany):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\NewsCustomer;

/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer",  options={"collate"="utf8mb4_general_ci", "charset"="utf8mb4"})
 */
class Customer 
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="integer")
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @var NewsCustomer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsCustomer", mappedBy="customer")
     */

    private $newsCustomer;

    /**
     * Customer constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->newsCustomer = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * To string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->number);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set number
     *
     * @param integer $number
     *
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get number
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    /**
     * Add newsCustomer
     *
     * @param NewsCustomer $newsCustomer
     *
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function addNewsCustomer(NewsCustomer $newsCustomer)
    {
        $this->newsCustomer[] = $newsCustomer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove newsCustomer
     *
     * @param NewsCustomer $newsCustomer
     */
    public function removeNewsCustomer(NewsCustomer $newsCustomer)
    {
        $this->newsCustomer->removeElement($newsCustomer);
    }

    /**
     * Get newsCustomer
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getNewsCustomer()
    {
        return $this->newsCustomer;
    }
}
```

Y mi form builder en la clase `CustomerAdmin`:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->tab('General')
            ->add('id', 'text', [
                'disabled'  => true
            ])
            ->add('number')
            ->end()->end()
            ->tab('News')
            ->add('newsCustomer', 'sonata_type_collection',
                array(
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'mapped' => true
                ),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table'
            ));
```

Alguno tiene una idea de como puedo hacer algo así? He probado con sonata type model pero no me permite editar.

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve yo lo hago asi:

> add('newsCustomer', 'sonata_type_collection',
>                   array(
>                       'by_reference' => false,
>                       'mapped' => true
>                   ),
>                   array(
>                       'edit' => 'inline',
>                       'inline' => 'Default'
>               ));

Comment: Bienvenido podrias agregar mas información de como es que llegaste a esta solución